# Приложение вылетает при запуске без отладки, если я запускаю через отладку этой ошибки нет

Tags: java, android

При отладке приложения через Android Studio, приложение работает, не вылетает.
Только высунул кабель, пытаюсь запустить через иконку на рабочем столе. Пишет в работе приложения снова сбой, перезапустить приложение?
Получается при самом старое программы, ничего не появляется, сразу вылет.

Логи:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anton.familybudget/com.example.anton.familybudget.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference



 public void Update(){
    UpdateSumma();

   if(getIntent ().getExtras ()!= null) {
       switch (getIntent ().getStringExtra ("Fragment")) {
           case "General":
               MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().
                       replace (R.id.flFragment, new Fragment_Coasts (), "FragmentCoasts")
                       .commit ();
               break;
           case "Incoming":
               MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ()
                       .replace (R.id.flFragment, new Fragment_Incoming (), "FragmentIncoming")
                       .commit ();
               break;
       }
   }
       else{
       MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().
               replace (R.id.flFragment, new Fragment_Coasts (), "FragmentCoasts")
               .commit ();
   }
   }
```

Comment: Приведите логи ошибки и место в коде где вылетает. По текущему описанию сказать в чём проблема - нельзя.

Comment: Попробуйте отключить в студии `InstantRun`

Answer (score 0):

Решилась проблема вот таким путем
      if(getIntent ()!= null && getIntent ().hasExtra ("Fragment"))